# Is there any way to find out if a certain button is clicked in a cross-domain child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, parent-child

Is there any way to find if a certain button is clicked in a cross-domain child window which I can't edit? Or if a POST action is made to a certain URL from the child window?

Here is an HTML tag for the button and it posts parameters to a certain URL.

```
<button type="button" class="postButton">POST</button>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: one word NO because you'll get a cross-origin error , but you could try creating a browser extension

Answer (score 1):

No. Since it's cross-origin, you can't access the child window's document in order to hook up event handlers on its elements.